# Proving uniform convergence of a function+

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Let $f_{n},g_{n}:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be given by $g_{n}(x)=\frac{2nx}{1+n^3x^2}$ and $f_{n}(x)=\frac{\log(1+n^3x^2)}{n^2}$

Show that $g_{n}(x)$ converges uniformly to $0$. (Completed)

Now use this this to show that $f_{n}(x)$ also converges uniformly to $0$

Obviously I need to make use of $f_{n}(x)=\frac{\log(2nx)-\log(g_{n}(x))}{n^2}$, just not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding using $f_n$, here's a hint. Note that $g_n=f_n'$. We have
$$ |f_n(x)| = \left|f(0) + \int_0^x g_n(y)dy\right|\le |f(0)| + \int _0^1 |g_n(y)| dy $$

Though the other answer was pretty simple

Comment: So how do I conclude? The term on the far right tends to zero as $n\rightarrow \infty$? And $f(0)=0$? Which shows $f_{n}(x)$ converges uniformly?

Comment: @Loobear23 yeah. I guess I gave more of a sketch than a hint